# Counting repeated word in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, jupyter

I have a dataframe containing people's order of the t-shirt. `df['Order']` is the column name that contains each customer's order. I want to count how many times `Burger M`, `Donut L`, `Ice Cream L` etc. appear for different design and sizes and then graph them on a bar chart. I tried groupby and count but it's only based on same item in each role, it doesn't count the individual word.

```
Customer name     Order
Sam Doe           Donut L, Burger L, Burger M
John Doe          Burger M
Sammy Doe         Burger M, Donut L
Jonny Doe         Burger L
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing along this:

```
orders = df['Order'].str.split(', ').explode().value_counts()

orders.plot.bar()
```

Or:

```
orders = df['Order'].str.get_dummies(', ').sum()

orders.plot.bar()
```